Page requires definePageMeta, otherwise remote error 500 occurs
When deploying my Nuxt app on Heroku, I encountered a strange 500 error which I was unable to reproduce locally or see any relevant warning about. I want to squash this and not have it bite me again in a year. Am I overlooking a simple concept?
Observation
On remote, I get a 500 error trying to open the app homepage. I could see the error page was a Nuxt error page, telling me Nuxt itself seemed to be successfully loading and that the 500 error likely stemmed from within the app.
Cause
After much trial-and-error, found that a simple page link was the issue:
App.vue header
Fails - app has 500 error:
<NuxtLink :to="{ name: 'MySimplePage' }">MySimplePage</NuxtLink>

Works - no 500 error
<!-- <NuxtLink :to="{ name: 'MySimplePage' }">MySimplePage</NuxtLink> -->

Solution
I added definePageMeta with name property to MySimplePage; it didn't have it yet as it was a new page. Eventually it would have gotten this, along with a bunch of other properties, similar to all of my other pages.
/src/pages/MySimplePage.vue
Added...
definePageMeta({
    name: 'MySimplePage'
})

Now my app works, with all requisite links, and no 500 errors.
Questions
1 - Why was definePageMeta needed?
It's my understanding Nuxt makes proper named routes from the mere existence of the page file (ie /src/pages/MySimplePage.vue). This is the case on local, and I've never ran into any problems.
2 - Why didn't anything on local warn me about this?
On local, I cannot reproduce this 500 error; everything works fine in the original form.
No local errors/warnings...

Running dev
Running build
Running preview
Running start
Running Heroku-specific preview (e.g. heroku local web --port 5001)

... and the local app loads fine in my browser.

It might be strict behaviour in Heroku.
